# Insert bibliography in a table cell

Tags: tables, biblatex

Is there a way to insert a bibliography from a `refsection` right into a table cell? Or maybe there is a workaround to make it look like a table cell.

An importante note is that there are other cells in the table, and the table has several columns of known widths.

**Solution**

The final variant appeared to be

```
\begin{tabular}{c p{5cm} p{11cm}}
42 & Bibliography & \nocite{*} {\printbibliography[heading=none]} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Note the braces around `\printbibliography[heading=none]`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077). I do not know exactly how the result should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a minipage to wrap the subbibliography. M(ish)WE, with five random references in `sample.bib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{First part}
\begin{refsection}
See the following: \cite{a,b,c}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
a & b & c\\
\hline
\begin{minipage}{8cm}\vspace{2mm}\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]\end{minipage} & d & e\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\section{Second part}
See also: \cite{d,e}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly, the `minipage` environment didn't help. Finally, I surrounded `\printbibliography[heading=none]` with braces, and then all errors disappeared. Thanks anyway.